# Why does changing one `np.nan` value change all of the nan values in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, nan

When I change one value in the entire DataFrame, it changes other values.  Compare scenario 1 and scenario 2:

Scenario 1:  Here notice that I only have `float(np.nan)` values for `NaN`s

```
info_num = np.array([[random.randint(0,9) for x in range(4)]+['ui'],
[random.randint(0,8) for x in range(3)]+[float(np.nan)]+['g'],
[random.randint(0,7) for x in range(2)]+[float(np.nan)]+[90]+[float(np.nan)],
[random.randint(0,9) for x in range(4)]+['q'],
[random.randint(0,9) for x in range(4)]+['w']])

result_df = pd.DataFrame(data=info_num, columns=['G','Bd', 'O', 'P', 'keys'])

result_df = result_df.fillna(0.0)  # does NOT fill in NaNs
```

The result of Scenario 1 is just a dataframe without the NaNs filled in.

Scenario 2:  Here notice that I only have `None` value in ONE spot

```
info_num = np.array([[random.randint(0,9) for x in range(4)]+['ui'],
[random.randint(0,8) for x in range(3)]+[None]+['g'],
[random.randint(0,7) for x in range(2)]+[float(np.nan)]+[90]+[float(np.nan)],
[random.randint(0,9) for x in range(4)]+['q'],
[random.randint(0,9) for x in range(4)]+['w']])

result_df = pd.DataFrame(data=info_num, columns=['G','Bd', 'O', 'P', 'keys'])

result_df = result_df.fillna(0.0)  # this works!?!
```

Even though I only fill in one of the NaN values with None, the other `float(np.nan)`s get filled in with `0.0`, as if they are `NaN`s too.

Why is there some relationship between the `NaN`s?

Comment: Some weirdness in the underlying default typing system of pandas. For some reason adding the `None` causes the default value to be a `float`. Without this the default type is being interpreted as a `str`. You can explicitly set the the type and fix the issues.

Comment: Okay....so if I actually want to literally fill with `NaN` values as they will be interpreted in `fillna`, what do I use?

Comment: You could convert your `'nan'` as string to `NaN` with `replace` method: `df.replace('nan', np.nan)`

Answer (score 1):

The 1st `info_num` is `dtype='S3'` (strings). In the 2nd it is `dtype=object`, a mix of integers, `nan` (a float) and strings (and a `None`).

In the dataframes I see something that prints as 'nan' in the one, and a mix of `None` and `NaN` in the other. It looks like `fillna` treats `None` and `NaN` the same, but ignores a string 'nan'.

The doc for `fillna`

> Fill NA/NaN values using the specified method

Pandas `NaN` is the same as `np.nan`.

`fillna` uses `pd.isnull` to determine where to put the `0.0` value.

```
def isnull(obj):
    """Detect missing values (NaN in numeric arrays, None/NaN in object arrays)
```

For the 2nd case:

```
In [116]: pd.isnull(result_df)
Out[116]: 
       G     Bd      O      P   keys
0  False  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False   True  False
2  False  False   True  False   True
3  False  False  False  False  False
4  False  False  False  False  False
```

(its all `False` for the first, string, case).

---

```
In [121]: info_num0
Out[121]: 
array([['4', '8', '5', '6', 'ui'],
       ['1', '5', '6', 'nan', 'g'],
       ['6', '1', 'nan', '90', 'nan'],
       ['5', '2', '8', '4', 'q'],
       ['1', '6', '4', '3', 'w']], 
      dtype='<U3')
In [122]: info_num
Out[122]: 
array([[1, 8, 3, 0, 'ui'],
       [1, 5, 1, None, 'g'],
       [0, 2, nan, 90, nan],
       [7, 7, 1, 4, 'q'],
       [3, 7, 0, 3, 'w']], dtype=object)
```

---

`np.nan` is `float` already:

```
In [125]: type(np.nan)
Out[125]: float
```

---

If you'd added `dtype=object` to the initial array definition, you'd get the same effect as using that `None`:

```
In [140]: np.array([[random.randint(0,9) for x in range(4)]+['ui'],
[random.randint(0,8) for x in range(3)]+[np.nan]+['g'],
[random.randint(0,7) for x in range(2)]+[np.nan]+[90]+[np.nan],
[random.randint(0,9) for x in range(4)]+['q'],
[random.randint(0,9) for x in range(4)]+['w']],dtype=object)
Out[140]: 
array([[6, 7, 8, 1, 'ui'],
       [5, 2, 5, nan, 'g'],
       [3, 0, nan, 90, nan],
       [5, 2, 1, 3, 'q'],
       [1, 7, 7, 2, 'w']], dtype=object)
```

Better yet, create the initial data as a list of lists, rather than an array.  `numpy` arrays have to uniform elements; with a mix of ints, nan, and strings you only get that with `dtype=object`.  But that is little more than an array wrapper around a list.  Python lists already allow this kind of diversity.

```
In [141]: alist = [[random.randint(0,9) for x in range(4)]+['ui'],
[random.randint(0,8) for x in range(3)]+[np.nan]+['g'],
[random.randint(0,7) for x in range(2)]+[np.nan]+[90]+[np.nan],
[random.randint(0,9) for x in range(4)]+['q'],
[random.randint(0,9) for x in range(4)]+['w']]
In [142]: alist
Out[142]: 
[[4, 0, 2, 6, 'ui'],
 [3, 3, 3, nan, 'g'],
 [3, 5, nan, 90, nan],
 [4, 0, 6, 7, 'q'],
 [0, 8, 3, 8, 'w']]
In [143]: result_df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=alist, columns=['G','Bd', 'O', 'P', 'keys'])
In [144]: result_df1
Out[144]: 
   G  Bd   O   P keys
0  4   0   2   6   ui
1  3   3   3 NaN    g
2  3   5 NaN  90  NaN
3  4   0   6   7    q
4  0   8   3   8    w
```

I'm not sure how pandas stores this internally, but `result_df1.values` does return an object array.

```
In [146]: result_df1.values
Out[146]: 
array([[4, 0, 2.0, 6.0, 'ui'],
       [3, 3, 3.0, nan, 'g'],
       [3, 5, nan, 90.0, nan],
       [4, 0, 6.0, 7.0, 'q'],
       [0, 8, 3.0, 8.0, 'w']], dtype=object)
```

So if a column has a `nan`, all the numbers a float (`nan` is a kind of float).  The first 2 columns remain integer.  The last is a mix of strings and that `nan`.

But `dtypes` suggest that pandas is using a structured array, with each column being a `field` with the relevant dtype.

```
In [147]: result_df1.dtypes
Out[147]: 
G         int64
Bd        int64
O       float64
P       float64
keys     object
dtype: object
```

The equivalent `numpy` dtype would be:

```
dt = np.dtype([('G',np.int64),('Bd',np.int64),('O',np.float64),('P',np.float64), ('keys',object)])
```

We can make a structured array with this dtype.  I have to turn the list of lists into a list of tuples (the structured records):

```
X = np.array([tuple(x) for x in alist],dt)
```

producing:

```
array([(4, 0, 2.0, 6.0, 'ui'), 
       (3, 3, 3.0, nan, 'g'),
       (3, 5, nan, 90.0, nan), 
       (4, 0, 6.0, 7.0, 'q'), 
       (0, 8, 3.0, 8.0, 'w')], 
      dtype=[('G', '<i8'), ('Bd', '<i8'), ('O', '<f8'), ('P', '<f8'), ('keys', 'O')])
```

That can go directly into Pandas as:

```
In [162]: pd.DataFrame(data=X)
Out[162]: 
   G  Bd   O   P keys
0  4   0   2   6   ui
1  3   3   3 NaN    g
2  3   5 NaN  90  NaN
3  4   0   6   7    q
4  0   8   3   8    w
```